# How to use onDelete: 'CASCADE' on one-to-one relationship

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I try to delete user's profile when user was deleted. But it's delete nothing on profile.

User Entity

```
@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToOne(type => Profile, profile => profile.user, 
              { eager: true, cascade: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    @JoinColumn()
    profile: Profile;

}
```

Profile Entity

```
@Entity()
export class Profile {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    gender: string;

    @Column()
    photo: string;

    @OneToOne(type => User, user => user.profile)
    user: User;

}
```

How I delete a user.

```
const userRepository = connection.getRepository(User);
const user = await userRepository.findOne({ where: {id: 'someuserId'}, relations: ["profile"] });

await user.remove()
```

User was removed but nothing happen on user's profile.

> Can anyone explain how to delete relationship on one-to-one?

Comment: If you look at the actual tables in your SQL database, is there an actual cascade configured?

Comment: here is in Users --> CONSTRAINT `FK_ef7a0cc61d7873284f1cedc5d5d` FOREIGN KEY (`profileId`) REFERENCES `profile` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: and this --> UNIQUE KEY `REL_ef7a0cc61d7873284f1cedc5d5` (`profileId`)

@AluanHaddad

Comment: In SQL, the `cascade` specification belongs on the child or dependent table in the relationship. I assume that `Profile` depends on `User`, so you probably need to put the cascade specification on the other end of the relationship in the decorator.

Comment: `user.remove()` is this syntax correct? remove does not exist on user entity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***User***

```
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @OneToOne(type => Profile, profile => profile.user, 
              { eager: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    @JoinColumn()
    profile: Profile;
}
```

***Profile***

```
@Entity()
export class Profile {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    gender: string;

    @Column()
    photo: string;

    @OneToOne(type => User, user => user.profile, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    user: User;

}
```

I ran this code for removing entries from both the entities.

```
const userRepository = connection.getRepository(User);
const user = await userRepository.findOne({ where: {id: 'someuserId'} });

const profileRepository = connection.getRepository(Profile);
const profile = await profileRepository.findOne({ where: {id: user.profile.id} });

await profileRepository.remove(profile)
```

This is the expected behaviour for one-to-one relation. **You have to delete referencing side to take cascade deletion to take in effect.** discussion [link](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1460#issuecomment-439996651)

**edit:** raised issue on [github](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6764)

Comment: I try to define onDelete: "CASCADE" in both entities. profile still not remove. 
Should I change its to Many-to-one ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention some points. Check my answer again

Comment: That is a really counterintuitive API. Specifying it on both ends makes the code read as if deleting either end will cascade delete the other, I assume the owner is not subject to deletion if the owned entity is deleted.

Comment: Sadly, That's how it is working. I'll raise an issue on typeorm github.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

I recently found myself in the same spot. I created a inheritance relationship in my database. Multiple entities reference one common entity which provides basic attributes for each specialized table. For example: Common attribute holder table "Car" and specialized tables "Truck", "Bus". Now I wanted to delete the corresponding "Car"-entity whenever a "Truck" or "Bus" is deleted.

In typeorm the specialized tables should reference the common attribute table. To make the `CASCADE DELETE` work, you have to specify the side which holds the id using the `@JoinColumn()` annotation. Then you have to specify the `onDelete: "CASCADE"` on the One-to-One relationship of the same side as the `@JoinColumn()` annotation.

To validate the created table you can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` in your database. There you will see if the `CASCADE DELETE` is present on the correct foreign key constraint. (It should be on the table holding the foreign key).

That means, it is not required to set the `CASCADE DELETE` on both sides.

## Code example

(see Gaurav Sharma's answer - modified)

```js
// referenced table
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    // you can use eager on the none-owning side
    // this can be very helpful for inheritance
    @OneToOne(type => Profile, profile => profile.user, { eager: true })
    profile: Profile;
}


// owning side - foreign key in this table
@Entity()
export class Profile {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    gender: string;

    @Column()
    photo: string;

    // specify onDelete here because owning side FK constraint would fail 
    // and it needs to know what is going to happen
    @OneToOne(type => User, user => user.profile, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    @JoinColumn()
    user: User;

}
```

From here on you would create a new user. Set the saved user in the profile to save and save the profile.
Deleting the profile will not delete the user.
Deleting the user will delete the profile.

I also looked into `CASCADE DELETE` from both sides. From what I have found, you would have to specify the `@JoinColumn()` annotation on both sides, declaring `onDelete: "CASCADE"` on both sides. This will require at least two saves for new entities and I did not find further information in the docs concerning the bidirectional `CASCADE DELETE`. I would consider deleting manually in these situations because it might become very unclear what is going to happen and when entities need to be saved.

Answer (score -3):

I solved my problem (for now)

I just manual remove in both entities.

```
const userRepository = connection.getRepository(User);
const user = await userRepository.findOne({ where: {id: 'someuserId'}, relations: ["profile"] });

const profileRepository = connection.getRepository(Profile);
const profile = await profileRepository.findOne({where: {id: user.profile.id}}).getOne()

await profile.remove()
await user.remove()
```

Comment: See my answer again. I ran that code on my machine.