# Cascade delete in Typeorm for one-to-one

Tags: typeorm

I read and searched a lot but did not find any solution to my problem. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002621/how-to-use-ondelete-cascade-on-one-to-one-relationship), [this](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3218), ...

My database is MySQL. There is no problem with one-to-many and many-to-many. in one-to-one relation

```
// Student.ts(Parent)

@Entity({ name: "student" })
export class StudentEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    public name: string;

    @OneToOne(() => StudentProfile, (profile) => profile.student, { onDelete: "CASCADE", cascade: ['insert', 'update'] })
    public profile: StudentProfile
}


// Profile.ts

@Entity({ name: "profile" })
export class StudentProfile {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    username: string

    @OneToOne(() => StudentEntity, (student) => student.profile, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    public student: StudentEntity
}
```

Now, With The following code I want to remove the student and their profile:

```
const student = await this._studentRepository.findOne({ where: { id: 4 } })
await this._studentRepository.delete(student)
```

The code above does not work. there is another way: I can remove the student and profile individually, I do not want to do this.

any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As [the stackoverflow you included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64002621/how-to-use-ondelete-cascade-on-one-to-one-relationship), mentions: **You have to delete referencing side to take cascade deletion to take in effect.**

I guess you've to delete like:

```js
const student = await this._studentRepository.findOne({ where: { id: 4 } })
const profile = await this._profileRepository.findOne({ where: { id: student.profile } }) // if you don't have an eager relationship
await this._profileRepository.delete(profile)
```

or in case of an eager relationship between student and profile:

```js
const student = await this._studentRepository.findOne({ where: { id: 4 } })
await this._profileRepository.delete(student.profile) // if you've an eager relationship
```